# Accessing/segmenting columns in a numpy recarray

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

Python beginner here. I've embarrassingly spent the past two hours trying to figure this out.

I've got a `CSV` file containing data from rows 14 to 86 and columns `A` to `X`. I bring this into a `NumPy` `recarray` using `csv2rec`. The data imports fine, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to create separate arrays from different rows of columns. For that matter I can't figure out how to reference a column of the `recarray`.

To reference the row, I can just call `array_name[0]` for the first row or `array_name[1]` for the second row (`array_name` being the name of the array).

I've tried my interpretation of what I see on the tentative `NumPy` [tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5):

```
array_name[0:5, 1]
```

I did this to grab the second column at rows 1-4 (even though what I really want is the whole column), but even that doesn't work.

Ultimately I'm trying to plot `3d` lines from `CSV` data in `Matplotlib`, but I need to get past this first step.

Answer (score 1):

turns out the header of the column of my csv is all I need.

For example, if the header row of my column was "data1" The code would be
    array_name['data1'] to pull the whole column